# Semi-algebra generating $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, semialgebras

I would like to know if the collection $\mathcal{S}$ consisting of intervals $[a,b)$ with $a\leq b$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, is a semi-algebra. I'm familiar with the standard definition:

- $\emptyset\in\mathcal{S}$
- $A,B\in\mathcal{S} \Rightarrow A\cap B\in\mathcal{S}$
- $\forall A \in \mathcal{S}: A^\mathrm{c} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i$ with $\{E_1,\ldots,E_n\}\subset \mathcal{S}$, disjoint.

The above mentioned collection does not satisfy the third condition. However, here [https://math.byu.edu/~bakker/Math541/Lectures/M541Lec11.pdf](https://math.byu.edu/%7Ebakker/Math541/Lectures/M541Lec11.pdf) I found an alternative definition of semi-algebra with which $\mathcal{S}$ complies (see the example under the definition).

Is this a more general definition of semi-algebra?

Comment: Assuming that $\mathcal{S}$ is not empty, the definition in the pdf file is actually the definition of **semiring** of sets, which is more general than the definition of semi-algebra. See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets#Related_structures

Comment: The collection $\mathcal{S}$ consisting of intervals $[a,b)$ with $a\leq b$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, is **not** a semi-algebra, but it is a semiring (of sets).

Comment: @Ramiro I understand. I was trying to use $\mathcal{S}$ in the standard ergodic theoretic application, where you "check" a certain property just for a generating semi-algebra. Would you happen to know if you could do a similar thing with a semiring in the $\sigma$-finite setting?

Comment: Yes. If $\mathcal{S}$ is a semiring of subsets of $\Omega$ and $\Omega$ can be covered by a countable collection of elements in $\mathcal{S}$, then $\Sigma$, the $\sigma$-ring generated by $\mathcal{S}$, is in fact a $\sigma$-algebra.  In other words, you can replace $\mathcal{S}$ by $\mathcal{A}$, the smallest semi-algebra containing $\mathcal{S}$ and then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ will be the same $\Sigma$ (the $\sigma$-ring generated by $\mathcal{S}$).